# ksh + irregular ksh syntax to support float numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

In my ksh script I have the parameter `VERSION=3.9.2X`. `$VERSION` always start with `3.9.2` and `X` could be any number integer or float number.

The following irregular ksh syntax works fine for any X integer number/s but not for float  numbers (for example it doesn't work for `X=2.34` or `X=22.123`)

What do I need to add in my syntax in order to support float numbers?

```
[[ $VERSION = 3.9.2*([0-9]) ]] && echo right version
```

- remark - X could have the character  "-"

Example of  $VERSION values that could be

```
          VERSION=3.9.22.34-3
          VERSION=3.9.20.34.3
          VERSION=3.9.29.34-3
          VERSION=3.9.212.3.4-3
          VERSION=3.9.21.34.2-3.3
          VERSION=3.9.273
          VERSION=3.9.210.3
```

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail the format of a "right version"? How many parts separated but dots `.` can it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want? not sure...

```
kent$  ksh
$ VERSION=3.9.21.2.3.4.5
$ [[ $VERSION = 3.9.2*([0-9\.]) ]] && echo $VERSION
3.9.21.2.3.4.5
```

**EDIT**

```
kent$  ksh
$ VERSION=3.9.21.2.3.4.5-34556
$ [[ $VERSION = 3.9.2*([0-9\.-]) ]] && echo $VERSION
3.9.21.2.3.4.5-34556
```

**EDIT2**

```
$ VERSION=3.9.21.2.3.4.5-345_5-60_2-3
$ [[ $VERSION = 3.9.2*([_0-9\.-]) ]] && echo $VERSION
3.9.21.2.3.4.5-345_5-60_2-3
```

Comment: HI kent see my update float number can have also the "-" char

Comment: @Eytan see the EDIT in answer

Comment: Hi kent - last question in case I also have the _ char I can add this after the "-" as [[ $VERSION = 3.9.2*([0-9\.-_]) ]] ????